# Mongodb worker role throws System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-storage

I have an Azure cloud project which makes use of mongodb worker roles. When running in the local emulator everything works fine, however when I deploy to an Azure staging area, the mongodb worker roles are stuck cycling and show a System.IO.FileNotFoundException. I connected to one of the virtual machines remotely and looked at the event viewer and found the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred. Type: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>   Process ID: 1936 Process Name: WaWorkerHost Thread ID: 4 AppDomain
>   Unhandled Exception for role MongoDB.WindowsAzure.MongoDBRole_IN_0
>   Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'mswacdmi, Version=1.7.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudDrive..ctor(Uri uri,
>   StorageCredentials credentials)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudStorageAccountCloudDriveExtensions.CreateCloudDrive(CloudStorageAccount
>   storageAccount, String pageBlobUri)    at
>   MongoDB.WindowsAzure.MongoDBRole.Utilities.GetMountedPathFromBlob(String
>   localCachePath, String cloudDir, String containerName, String
>   blobName, Int32 driveSize, CloudDrive& mongoDrive) in
>   c:\Users\Matt\Software\AzurePrototype1\mongo-azure-master\src\MongoDB.WindowsAzure.MongoDBRole\Utilities.cs:line
>   78    at
>   MongoDB.WindowsAzure.MongoDBRole.MongoDBRole.GetMongoDataDirectory()
>   in c:\Users\Matt\Software\AzurePrototype1\mongo-azure-master\src\MongoDB.WindowsAzure.MongoDBRole\MongoDBRole.cs:line 255    at MongoDB.WindowsAzure.MongoDBRole.MongoDBRole.StartMongoD()
>   in c:\Users\Matt\Software\AzurePrototype1\mongo-azure-master\src\MongoDB.WindowsAzure.MongoDBRole\MongoDBRole.cs:line 201    at MongoDB.WindowsAzure.MongoDBRole.MongoDBRole.OnStart() in
>   c:\Users\Matt\Software\AzurePrototype1\mongo-azure-master\src\MongoDB.WindowsAzure.MongoDBRole\MongoDBRole.cs:line 91    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRoleInternal(RoleType
>   roleTypeEnum)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.b__0()
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Why does this work locally and not on Azure? I don't understand much about assemblies and such, but I am learning as I go along. One of the things suggested online is to check the properties of references assemblies and set 'Copy Local' to true, I have tried this but still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your worker role project, Make sure you have a .NET reference to `mswacdmi.dll` with the Properties set [**Copy Local=true**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t1zz5y8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). When you publish - [RDP to your Azure role instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg443832.aspx) to verify that your deployed role has the assembly in the `/bin` directory.

Also make sure you are targeting x64 - I found `mswacdmi.dll` at this path (*Azure SDK 1.8*):

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure.NET SDK\2012-10\bin\runtimes\storage\cloud\x64

Comment: I tried this, but still doesn't work :/ Copy local is set to true and I also tried copying the file into both the Debug and Release folders of /bin but still nothing. When deploying the file is not copied onto the virtual machine in /approot like the other libraries. Could it be because the version of mswacdmi.dll that I have is version 1.8 and it is looking for version 1.7? Still shouldn't the file get copied at least? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Something is certainly looking for 1.7 (*could be app.config reference or other assembly dependency*), so you should find that version here: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\2012-06\bin\runtimes\storage\cloud\x64` if you have **SDK 1.7** installed. Also, when you compile your Azure project, you should be able to change the `cspkg` file to `.zip` and find a `cssx` (*another zip archive*) which contains the contents of what gets uploaded to the Azure instance. From here, you should be able to track where it's getting lost. How are you deploying the package?

Comment: Ok got it to stop throwing the exception! I had to install SDK 1.7 and after it threw another filenotfound exception for another dll, but removing and re-adding the reference fixed it. So thanks for the help :) Do you have any idea why the references might be getting screwed up?

Comment: It could be a dependency from another component - check the `app.config` for your **MongoDBRole**. Something must be pointing to version 1.7.